# Need to generate a cluster of points in k-dimensional space in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

The points generated should be something like this-

```
21   32   34   54   76   34
23   55   67   45   75   23.322
54   23   45   76   85.1 32
```

the above example is when k=6.
How can I generate such a cluster of say around 1000 points and vary the value of k and the radius of the cluster.

Is there any built-in function that can do this for me? I can use any other tool if needed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The question is very unclear. What has _k_ got to do with your list? What's the 'cluster'? Most important, what have _you_ tried? Have you tried enough before posting this question? If you have, what are your findings?

Comment: Is that list actually supposed to be a list of 3 6-dimensional points that you forgot to put line breaks in-between?

Comment: the algorithm is based on k-means clustering. So k is the no of dimensions. For instance, k can be viewed as the no. of attributes for an object.

Sorry about the data it should be as follows:
(21 32 34 54 76 34),
    (23 55 67 45 75 23.322),
    (54 23 45 76 85.1 32)

So this are 3 points in a 6-dimensional space. These points will be belonging to a cluster of say radius 10. I need to find a way to generate around 1000 points by varying the radius of the cluster for a specific value of k

Comment: What's the center of the hypersphere? Should the coordinates be random? And why are most coordinates integral? If you need to improve your question, please edit it instead of putting it in comments here.

Comment: The co-ordinates can be any number, not necessarily integral. We can choose any point as the center of the hypersphere and the co-ordinates can be evenly distributed or be random and can either lie on the surface of the hypersphere or within the hypersphere

Comment: In that case you'd have to write your own code, I guess, which should be pretty short and straightforward. I don't think this task is standard enough that you'd find a function for it.

Comment: For 2D only you can use this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37435-generate-data-for-clustering

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/). It comes with a quite flexible data generator for clustering datasets, and there is a 640d subspace clustering example somewhere on the wiki.

Consider using `d` for the dimensionality, as when you are talking about clusters `k` usually refers to the number of clusters (think of k-means ...)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to write your own code for this. Supposing your center is at the origin, you have to pick *k* numbers, in sequence, with the constraint at every step that the sum of the squares of all the numbers upto (and including) it must not exceed the radius of the hypersphere squared. That is, the *k* th number squared must be less than or equal to the radius squared minus the sum of the squares of all previously picked numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the stats toolbox this is easy

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/stats/kmeans.html

Otherwise, you can quite easily write the code yourself using Lloyds algorithm.